# Why is TextFormat not working on my TextArea?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, adobe

I am trying to generate bold text on a text area once its clicked.  What am I doing wrong?

HelloWorld.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="800" height="800">
    <mx:Script source="HelloWorldAS.as" />

        <mx:VBox width="70%" height="70%" label="Container">
            <mx:TextArea id="lblTest"  verticalScrollPolicy="off" focusThickness="0" borderThickness="0" borderStyle="none" editable="true" fontFamily="Arial" fontSize="14" width="100%" height="100%" click="areaClick()"/>
        </mx:VBox>

</mx:Application>
```

HelloWorldAS.as

```
// ActionScript file
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;

public function areaClick() : void{
    lblTest.text = "Hello world!";

    var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    format.bold=true;

    lblTest.setStyle("textFormat", format);
    lblTest.validateNow();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no `textFormat` style for TextArea. Use `fontWeight` as `bold` as below:

```
lblTest.setStyle("fontWeight", "bold");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the official adobe documentation here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextFormat.html, the most interesting part for you is:

> Use the TextField.defaultTextFormat property to apply formatting
>   BEFORE you add text to the TextField, and the setTextFormat() method
>   to add formatting AFTER you add text to the TextField.

So if you want the text "hello world" to be bold, you must apply the TextFormat as follows:

```
lblText.setTextFormat(format);
```

Comment: thanks, but I am using it for a TextArea and not a TextField.  I tried setting lblTest.text = "Hello world!" after I set the format properties and its still not showing up.